# Flow (flowtype) and react: defaultProps are not controlled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Using the [v0.68.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.68.0), it seems that defaultProps are not controlled:

The code below (from [official doc](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props)) won't raise error when declaring the "foo" defaultProp (as a string instead of a number):

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";

type Props = {
  foo: number,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    foo: 'bad string',
  };
}
```

(See [TryFlow example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThwCECAC44AOwCuIAEZYoAGjoBfenVwAbNOgCyTAMIlIUrFPhYAHjAsATdNjwwAdCfARzlgDycI3AB8AkJwqDDIMMC4cPZYBMgy2jD+3HB8gsLCohJwAOTyyPZhMFDAUgDmearCGupAA))

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are checked when you try and create a component, i.e:

```
<MyComponent />
```

raises the appropriate error, see [TryFlow here](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThwCECAC44AOwCuIAEZYoAGjoBfenVwAbNOgCyTAMIlIUrFPhYAHjAsATdNjwwAdCfARzlgDycI3AB8AkJwqDDIMMC4cPZYBMgy2jD+3HB8gsLCohJwAOTyyPZhMFDAUgDmearCGuoMPoYeZhbwAPSBQA). This seems to be by design, as the conversation in [flow/#3499](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3499) indicates.